# Is it useful for a student trying to get an undergraduate research position to have a personal website?

Tags: cv, research-undergraduate, website

I'm studying a Bachelor in Engineering Physics undergraduate program and I know that most of the people that does research or that teaches have his/her personal website with their publications and their curriculum. I even know a friend of mine that has his own personal website. This made me think about creating one for myself. However, I don't really know if it really matters to have one now. I don't know if it is important to give my undergrad curriculum via personal website.

The things I'm including in the website will be:

**CV**

**Portfolio**

**Contact Information**

**Research Interests**

**About me** (section where I can talk about me in an extracurricular way)

So, will it matter if I do my website and include it in my signature whenever I send a mail to a professor looking to have a research stay or a research project with him?

Comment: This question is off topic for this site because it is specifically targeted at undergrads. If you want edit it so that it's more general, that would better.

Comment: This depends on what you want to do next (get a job? Go to grad school?) and what you would put on this website (info that's already on your CV? Portfolio of your projects?) There's no objective answer in the general case, but depending on the specifics there might be.

Comment: The intention is not that undergrads answer this, but researchers or people that has experience with this topic. It wouldn't give me any useful information if an undergrad answers this. @BenjaminMakoHill.

Comment: The website would contain the CV and its PDF format so people can download it, a portfolio of projects, educational videos and simulations, a "contact me", an "about me" (that contains doesn't relate with the curriculum), a "Science news" (with recomendable news), and a "Blog". @ff524

Comment: What Benjamin was saying is that questions about undergrad study are outside the scope of this site, as defined in the [help/on-topic]. If you ask about whether a personal website is useful for graduate admissions, or for getting an undergrad research position, it's on-topic; otherwise it's probably out of scope. (If you make it more general as he suggested, i.e., "Is it important for a student to have a personal website", it'll be on topic, but you'll get answers about grad students, which won't be useful to you.)

Comment: You _send a mail to a professor_   for what?

Comment: @scaaahu: In order to make an impression if I'm looking to have a research stay or a research project with him.

Comment: Please consider putting _looking to have a research stay or a research project with him_ in your question.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Undergraduate research is **on topic** here, as I mentioned in my previous comment, so I've reopened the question.

Comment: A website is an investment in academia, personal life, industry, or whatever. There is no guarantee your professor will look at it, but if they do, it will probably make your application to anywhere look better, especially if your portfolio contains samples of your work, which are only cited in the CV. If it isn't useful for this lab position, it will definitely be useful in the future.

Answer (score 3):

As just going through a round of interviews for hiring students to a research lab, I would say it is beneficial for you to have a website, on the condition that it is informative of your work.  Out of your list, the only one that I would view as beneficial is a portfolio.  Without the portfolio section, I would say it is not beneficial.

When people apply to my lab, they send their CV.  This usually includes some bullet points of work, school, extra curricular, etc.  The hardest part to extract from a CV is the type of work or actual capabilities of a student.  When receiving multiple applications, the ones that had a website were taken positively.   I was able to see not just the bullet points, but what type of work the student has previously done (Just be careful to be honest and full disclosure, if it was a group project, specify your role).

On the other hand, if your website gives no extra information than the CV, I would be a bit annoyed if I was directed to the website only to learn nothing more about the applicant.